# Triggering child builds with Bamboo automatic dependencies

Tags: maven, bamboo

We've configured Bamboo to use [automatic dependencies](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Setting+up+plan+build+dependencies#Settingupplanbuilddependencies-AutomaticdependencymanagementwithMaven3) based on Maven POM files. This appears to be working, insofar as the Bamboo interface correctly shows which the Maven artifacts required by and created by each plan, which upstream plans provide the dependencies and which downstream plans depend on the artifacts.

However, it also appears to not work, insofar as building an upstream artifact doesn't trigger a downstream build. Is it necessary to manually create child plans to trigger downstream builds -- an error-prone duplication of the information in the POM files? If so, the automatic dependency management isn't much use and it's hard to understand what the feature is for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a step in your parent build, using a script task to trigger whatever child build you'd like.

This way, you're not bounded by the Bamboo dependency/trigger mechanism.

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/65517/trigger-bamboo-plan-via-rest-call

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem with that solution is that the parent builds need to know about the child builds that depend on them, which means we need to duplicate (and probably introduce bugs into) all the dependency information in the POM files, backwards.